# Error : Fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: ios, git, xcode4

When I try to put images into the Resources folder of my project, I get this message:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you created project in XCode4 did you select the option where it would create a local git repository ? Have you committed the project to git ? Have you deleted any git references from the project folder later on ?

Comment: when i create new project, there is no option named something like : `create a local git repository`

Comment: Whats the XCode version you are using? Did you install GIT on your computer, did you add this project to Git ? Have you created this project from scratch or you are working on a copy that someone has created and worked on before

Comment: My Xcode version is 4.0.2, i am working on this project from scratch, i don't know what is GIT, i was working on the Xcode 3 and i didn't have any problem with that.

Comment: Hi again, i have found an option named : `Create local git repository for this project`, shall i select it or not?

Comment: No don't create it if you don't intend to use git. In your project folder do you see a .git directory ? if yes go ahead and remove it. Restart XCode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same problem. I copied a project then tried to delete files.

If you want to be able to edit the project, type git init *folder* in the terminal. This will re-initialize the git in your folder.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Organizer->Repositories and remove the Corresponding repository.

Comment: Thanks, it's the only solution that work for me. My XCode project is on git, but I don't want to use this crappy XCode git feature

Comment: I am with you 100% it is buggy.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how can I completely deactivate the Xcode git feature, because it's always coming back..

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem in Xcode 4.6.1 after moving my folder and xcodeproj file. Here's what works for me:

1. Delete corresponding repository in Organizer
2. Close Xcode
3. Delete the original .git directory
4. `git init` in the new directory where you placed the folder and xcodeproj file, and do an initial commit
5. Start Xcode

Answer (score 0):

In order to do anything in Git, you have to have a Git repository. This is where Git stores the data for the snapshots you are saving.

so just go into your project directory let say you have a project name test_project just go into that directory and type the command

```
git init
```

and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Perform these two steps in Xcode 11, to get rid of this error:

1. In the menu, select `Source Control` > `Create Git Repositories`.
2. Click on the `Create` button.