# Status of files like M and A from Local GIT repository is disabled in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, xcode4

The status of files like M and A is disabled in Xcode 4.5 from Local GIT repository in my machine.
How do I enable it so that I can view the status changes after SVN updates.

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7498850/6309, do you have two entries (svn and git) in your project organizer?