# How to deactivate the Xcode git feature? (remove git integration)

Tags: xcode, git

My Xcode project is on git, but I don't like the XCode git integration and sometime, I have [errors coming from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388560/error-fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git/14023458?noredirect=1#comment23887112_14023458)

So I would like to completely remove that feature of XCode. I tried to remove the repository in Organizer->Repository (but after a while, it comes up again).

Any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with just unticking the git checkbox when creating a new project?

Comment: I wouldn't try that personally, but maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6586957/14955

Comment: @Sha : I did ticked the git checkbox when creating the project. But my project is on git, so XBox automatically wants to manage it with git, but I prefer to do it outside of XCode

Comment: @Thilo : thanks, that's the answer of justin too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's unsupported, but it has appeared to work fine for me in the past:

- Quit Xcode
- Remove this bundle from its folder: `Xcode.app/Contents/Plugins/IDEGit.ideplugin` or change the bundle's extension.
- Restart Xcode

This disables the extension which provides git support in Xcode. You can still use Git for version control -- just not in Xcode.

Answer (score 12):

Remove `git` functionality from Xcode by disabling it in the preferences pane:

1. Open Xcode
2. Type `⌘,` (or `Xcode` menu > `Preferences...` row)
3. Switch to the `Source Control` pane
4. Toggle `Enable Source Control` off

Xcode 9:

[image]

Xcode 15:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable Git support in Xcode 4 you'll have to rename "/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEGit.ideplugin" to something other than .ideplugin

Have a look at this: [Remove git from project in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526366/remove-git-from-project-in-xcode-4)

It doesn't work in Xcode 4.2.1

You will have to remove the local git file. Refer to this: http://thompsonng.blogspot.sg/2012/03/xcode-remove-local-git-repository.html

Comment: According to comments on the linked answer, this doesn't work anymore. Workaround also in comments. And maybe community-wiki answers copied.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you wanted is only to deactivate version control in XCode, which is the same thing if you use git or SVN or whatever. If that's the case, check here: [Xcode 5 - remove source control for project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198514/xcode-5-remove-source-control-for-project)

I know that this thread is old, but if new people arrive here, this might be the right answer.

Cícero