# Xcode and disabling continuous integration with an already-existing Git folder

Tags: xcode, git, continuous-integration

I'm adding iOS support to a multiplatform project of mine. The folder structure looks as below:

```
/.git
/android (stores Android Visual Studio project files)
/source (stores all source)
/source/android (Android-specific source)
/source/windows (Windows-specific source)
/windows (stores Windows Visual Studio project files)
```

I've added a new /ios folder with an Xcode project, and a new /sources/ios folder for iOS-specific code. However, the Xcode project seems to be detecting the .git folder and auto-committing files (files that it modified itself e.g. replacing end of line characters) and modifying the index when I don't want it to even so much as look at it. I can't find a way to disable continuous integration within Xcode, is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667169/how-to-deactivate-the-xcode-git-feature-remove-git-integration

Comment: Yeah, but I was hoping in Xcode 6 there would be a supported way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667169/how-to-deactivate-the-xcode-git-feature-remove-git-integration) used to be a workaround for xcode 4, but in xcode 6 (and 5 also AFAIK), disabling git integration is a built in option.

Go to preferences

[image]

Go to the Source Control tab

[image]

Uncheck 'Enable Source Control'
You will want the screen to look like this

[image]

Comment: Whoa, how did I completely missed the Source Control option. I feel dumb...but thank you!